# Power Automate and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, send-email

I have created a library and added several folders in it (SharePoint Online). Whenever a document has been uploaded or edited, I would like to receive an email with a button/link to that document.
But this email needs to be just like the one Microsoft sends when you share a document with someone.

The thing is that we make use of Adobe Document Cloud. So opening the link, the pdf needs to open with Adobe Document Cloud. As of this far, I could only manage to get the document link as in "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/testlibrary/doc.pdf"

This link opens in the browser, but not in Adobe Document Cloud.
So if anyone here managed to get this working, please let me know.

Thank you.

[image: Mail from Microsoft]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an open behavior setting issue for PDF files.

Here’s the test result in my environment:

Since I don’t have access to Adobe Document Cloud, I have disabled the Adobe PDF Reader add-on in IE so that PDF files from SharePoint libraries will be opened in Adobe Reader client application.

The link sent by email is formatted as following: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Teamsite/Library/xxx.pdf

When I click the link, I get redirected to IE first, then the PDF file gets opened immediately in Adobe Reader client application.

So, I suggest you check if you have configured the open behavior for PDF files. You can also prevent the files from being opened in browser via IE > Settings > Managed add-ons > Adobe PDF Reader > Disable.

Reference:
[Using Adobe Document Cloud for SharePoint and OneDrive.](https://helpx.adobe.com/document-cloud/help/office365-using-sharepoint-onedrive.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But I've already found a solution for it.
This is creating a flow using an action "Create sharing link for a file or folder".
I suggest checking it out. It's a great tool.

Comment: ok congrates, I'll go check it out. Thanks for sharing.